# How to set up database(s) for a wiki family?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I have some issues setting up a wiki family with MediaWiki. Currently, I am working on two wikis with the same global settings, Penguin Ice Wikis and Penguiconverter. I also am not able to edit most of the Apache on the web host I run my wiki on. The users at MediaWiki's support desk told me to point the document roots of both wikis at a single place. However, when I make edits to the Penguiconverter wiki, the edits will also appear on the Penguin Ice Wikis wiki as well.

I added the upload location. When I did a test edit on my Penguiconverter wiki, the edit showed up on my Penguin Ice Wikis wiki. What can I do to make pages and edits separate on each wiki when they are pointed at a single place? I also added the database for Penguiconverter, and I got the following message: (Cannot access the database: Access denied for user 'gjlxrtap_penguinicewiki'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (localhost))

How do you fix both issues mentioned in the last paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it so the database prefix is set depending on the url a user has used to get to the wiki. You also need to make sure you have database tables with both wikis prefixes set up or alternatively two databases. All databases/tables need to be accessible to whichever database user you use.

Comment: I already have both databases set up. I also cloned the information from the old database by exporting the data and importing it into the new one. If this is the correct way to set up a new database, then what do I need to do to gain access to the database? If cloning by exporting and importing is the incorrect way, then what should the database look like?

Comment: EDIT: I also tried another way to create a database, by copying the structure only of the original database in order to create another database. However, I still got an access denied message for this database too.